# Windows hardlinks - why it consumes same space as original file

Tags: windows, deduplication, hardlink

Im using finddupe tool to de-duplicate files and save some space on HDD.
But checking before and after operation I cant see any free space released - see below.

Can somebody advise what is wrong here ?

```
D:\TEMP\1>dir
30.09.2021  12:50        89 028 146 polycom-410-copy.zip
30.09.2021  12:50        89 028 146 polycom-410.zip
               2 File(s)    178 056 292 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  117 821 751 296 bytes free

D:\TEMP\1>finddupe -hardlink d:\temp\1 Duplicate: 'd:\temp\1\polycom-410-copy.zip' With:      'd:\temp\1\polycom-410.zip'
    Created hardlink

Files:   178056 kBytes in     2 files Dupes:    89028 kBytes in     1 files

D:\TEMP\1>dir  Volume in drive D is BACKUP  Volume Serial Number is B66C-A894

 Directory of D:\TEMP\1
30.09.2021  12:50        89 028 146 polycom-410-copy.zip
30.09.2021  12:50        89 028 146 polycom-410.zip
               2 File(s)    178 056 292 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  117 910 781 952 bytes free


D:\TEMP\1>finddupe -listlink d:\temp\1


Hardlink group, 2 of 2 hardlinked instances found in search tree:   "d:\temp\1\polycom-410-copy.zip"   "d:\temp\1\polycom-410.zip"

Number of hardlink groups found: 1
```

Comment: Total size of files, and used spaced is different things, As mentioned in answer(s), used space did shrink (seen by looking at free space change)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What makes you think there was no space released?

```
# Before:
117 821 751 296 bytes free
# After:
117 910 781 952 bytes free
# Difference:
     89 030 656
# Your file size:
     89 028 146
```

You released pretty exactly the space of one file.

Comment: To expand, the total size reported by `dir` does not account for hardlinks, so it doesn't really report the *consumed* space.

Comment: Gosh I'm blind! I've looked wrong numbers!